# Insert first value from a table to another table Mysql PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with column x and column ID. I am trying to get the first value from  column x  and insert it into column y from table b.

here is what I have done and it doesn't work:

```
$val=mysql_query("SELECT x FROM table_a WHERE id=MIN(id)");
$sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO table_b (y) VALUES('$val')");
```

Also when I delete a value from table a column x I have to update the value from table b column y with previous value from table a.

Answer (score 2):

Try with [`SELECT INTO`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-select-into-table.html):

```
INSERT INTO table_b (y)
     SELECT MIN(table_a.id)
       FROM table_a
```

In PHP:

```
$sql=mysql_query('INSERT INTO table_b (y) SELECT MIN(table_a.id) FROM table_a');
```

Answer (score 1):

use `ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1` instead of instead of `MIN`:

```
$val=mysql_query("SELECT x FROM table_a ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1");
$sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO table_b (y) VALUES('$val')");
```

or with single query:

```
$sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO table_b (y) 
                 (SELECT x FROM table_a ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1)");
```

Comment: You are missing `mysql_fetch_assoc` after first query. Try second query.

Answer (score 0):

What your a doing is copying data from one table to another. There is no need for fetching the date first and then inserting it.

Use the [INSERT .. SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html) syntax.

Answer (score 0):

try it this way

```
$val=mysql_query("SELECT x FROM table_a WHERE id=MIN(id)");
$val_res = mysql_fetch_assoc($val);
$sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO table_b (y) VALUES('".$val_res['x']."')");
```

Comment: hey Sibu! I'm trying now to delete the whole row from the table where I have the value I have inserted,when I push a button.I am using something similar but it doesn't work and I don't understand why:    if(isset($_POST['_submit']))    { $val=mysql_query("SELECT x FROM table_a WHERE id=MIN(id)");
    $val_res = mysql_fetch_assoc($val);
    $sql=mysql_query("delete from table_b where y=".$val_res['x']."'");

Comment: @LauraDogariu check with this $val=mysql_query("SELECT x FROM table_a WHERE id=MIN(id)"); 
$val_res = mysql_fetch_assoc($val); 
$sql=mysql_query("delete from table_b where y=".$val_res['x']);

Comment: if I do like that it deletes only the value x in the table...I want to delete the whole row where value x is found.

Comment: @LauraDogariu in that case you will have to get all values in array and use foreach to delete each row

Comment: I don't know how to do that.Please help me

Comment: @LauraDogariu it cannot be explained in comments..pls ask that in another question..if you have got answers to this particular question please select your answer and ask new doubts in new question